# How To Make An Edit Text Float on top of toolbar and Main Layout

Tags: android, user-interface, android-toolbar, layout-animation

I want to achieve this kind of design [image]

As you can see the Edit text performs a nice animation to translate from the middle of the screen to the Top of the layout but i would like to know how achieve this.

I was thinking about wrapping the edit text inside a LinearLayout and when the Edit text reachs the Top the bacground just change to a gradient (white and yellow). Does that make sense??

Comment: whats the main feature you want to focus here can't help with all lazy to type

Comment: I want to achieve a search form for local files in android. Don't worry about the business logic (i have it already) i am just in need to achieve this kind of UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using creating a fragment with CardView as parent and EditText as child and then animating it along with the background.

Check this site to get a head start to animating fragments http://cyrilmottier.com/2014/05/20/custom-animations-with-fragments/

Comment: Looks like a useful tutorial. I will definitly give it a try.